# How is past Marty paradox explained in the Back to the Future series?

Tags: back-to-the-future

So Marty's parents are supposed to meet after his dad gets hit by his grandpa's car.   The mom and dad relive the stories about it.

After Marty time travels he is basically in their faces for a week trying to set them up after he messed up the original meeting (hit by car).   I mean he plays guitar at their dance.

So the paradox is... how the hell at Marty's age 13-14 did Lorraine or George not like say...  wow how the hell does our kid look EXACTLY like the guy that set us up for a week?

Comment: [Asked and answered on SciFi SE.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/back-to-the-future-flaw-why-dont-martys-parents-recognize-him-in-the-new-fut?r=SearchResults)

Comment: ...especially George!

Answer (score 3):

In the movie, Marty’s parents have to be in their forties. They have been out of high school for more than twenty years. Unless they have photographs of Marty in the 60s, they are not going to remember the exact details of how he looks after one week. It would be different if Marty was someone that they saw on a regular basis for months or years.

For instance, how often have you forgotten what someone looks like. Or even mistook someone for someone else. Now, think of that over a twenty to thirty year  gap.

Compound that with the fact that, in real life, Marty would resemble a mixture of or cross between his mother and his father. This familiarity and bond would have been strengthened and reinforced over the years of Marty’s life. Even before he is born, the movie portrays a familial bond between the 1960s Marty and his parents. His parents feel it. But, can’t recognize it or place its true source and meaning.

Comment: Marty travels 1985->1955, so it's been 30 years (plus or minus a few months).